# How to make this rotator have dynamic height based on content?

Tags: jquery, html, css-float, overflow, css-position

Please go to: http://jsfiddle.net/6zFt5/

As you can see, this rotator doesn't work without specifying a FIXED HEIGHT in line 6 of the CSS. I need this widget to dynamically adapt its height based on content height, without cutting it or leaving too much empty space.

Here is the css:

```
.rotator {
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 100%;
   border:1px solid red;
   height:auto; /*height:100px;*/
}
.rotator ul li {
   max-height: 100%; 
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color:aqua;
}
```

I left the jQuery script so you can understand what I am trying to use it for.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing would be to remove the

```
position: 'absolute'
```

from you js file

then, change the animation in the next() and prev() function in order for the ticket to run more smoothly

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zFt5/1/) out.

Comment: Thank you for help. Since the crossfading seems not to be an option if I want proper stacking, I ended up tweaking the js this way: http://jsfiddle.net/76rkL/